# csshX using a jumphost/bastion

Tags: ssh

I am currently using the following cmd to login to a ec2 instance using a jumphost -

ssh -J jumphost:2222 some_ip

I have installed csshX as I need to login to multiple instances simultaneously. I am not sure how to specify a jumphost in csshX.

Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ssh config, the default location being `~/.ssh/config` which has a similar configuration, and ssh client honours it.

```
Host 192.168.*.*
 ProxyCommand ssh jumphost -W %h:%p
```

and when you do `csshX 192.168.0.10`, it will go through the jumphost. (Tested and working from a mac.)